# Доступ к свойствам объекта в его методах JS

Tags: javascript

Дополни метод updateBook(oldName, newName) так, чтобы он изменял название книги с oldName на newName в свойстве books. Используй indexOf() для того, чтобы найти нужный элемент массива, и splice() для того чтобы заменить этот элемент
Задания

```
const bookShelf = {
  books: ['The last kingdom', 'Haze', 'The guardian of dreams'],
  updateBook(oldName, newName) {
    // Change code below this line
    
    // Change code above this line
  },
}
```

Мой метод ниже (Почему не работает?)

```
const bookShelf = { 
    books: ['The last kingdom', 'Haze', 'The guardian of dreams'], 
    updateBook(oldName, newName) { 
        // Change code below this line 
        
        const bookIndex = this.books.indexOf(oldName) 
        this.books.splice(bookIndex) 
    
        // Change code above this line 
    }, 
};
```

Comment: "Почему не работает?" --- потому что ты забыл что-то добавить вторым и третьим аргументом в splice?  (почитай https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Дополните пример!

Answer (score 2):

Метод **[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** принимает несколько аргументов, не только один единственный. Как минимум второй указывает на то, сколько элементов надо удалить. В вашем случае это количество 1.  Третий аргумент - что надо вставить.  В вашем случае это будет `newName`

Внимательно читайте документацию.